# Android App Support Options

Tags: android, marketplace

I've got a free app I'm planning on submitting to the marketplace. Looking over the submission form I see they expect a web site or email for support.

Users?! I've got to worry about users if I submit an app? I suppose I would like to get some abuse from users, but I don't want to go broke doing it.

So what are my options?

I have a web site--I suppose I could install forum software on it--that sounds like a lot of work though.

Some apps reference a blogspot page--or I could use my Word Press site. They seems a bit disorganized for getting user feedback though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a minimum, I would suggest having

- A blog where you post information and updates about the app (a project blog, not a personal blog that also contains project info)
- An email address where users can submit comments/complaints/bug reports

You don't need a full-blown forum necessarily, especially for a free app.  Users mainly want a way to communicate with you and to get updated information.  Unless it is an open-source app where users will be collaborating together to develop it, you don't really need anything as "social" as a forum.

Comment: Turns out my hosting account has a free, easy to setup forum option. I agree, a forum for a free throw-away app like the one I wrote is overkill. It was just so easy to setup the forum and I think monitoring the forum wil be easier than dealing with a published email address.

I'll create a web page for the app and link to my shiney new forum.